# How can I insert/replace values within a column based on preceding columns?

Tags: r

I have received a transaction log where I track students logging into a Learning Management System (LMS). I have already managed to spread the data into weeks. The resulting data.frame looked as follows:

```
UserID   31        32        33        34        35
user1    active    active    n/a       n/a       active
user2    n/a       n/a       active    active    n/a
user3    active    n/a       n/a       active    active
```

I need to insert or replace the column values based on the preceeding value into something like below:

```
UserID     31       32       33       34       35
user1      new      recur    drop     drop     recur
user2      n/a      n/a      new      recur    drop
user3      new      drop     drop     recur    recur
```

This is to show students login patterns which differentiate between new user logging for the first time, recurring users and users who did not log in for a particular week.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a read at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to make [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also include expected output and code that you tried and failed. And format your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The `duplicated` function can be used for this.

Perhaps a bit verbose like this but:

```
df <- data.frame(user1=c('n/a','active','n/a','active'),
                 user2=c('n/a','n/a','n/a','n/a'),
                 user3=c('active','n/a','active','n/a'),
                 user4=c('active','active','active','active'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

recode_col <- function(col) {
  coldup <- duplicated(col)
  colna <- col=='n/a'
  col[!coldup&!colna] <- 'new'
  col[coldup&!colna] <- 'recur'
  col[colna] <- 'drop'
  first_nonna <- which(!colna)[1]
  if (is.na(first_nonna)) first_nonna <- length(col)+1
  col[1:first_nonna-1] <- 'n/a'
  col
}

lapply(df, recode_col)
```